# how to use __sync_fetch_and_add in vs2019 under windows

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio-2019

I want to use **__sync_fetch_and_add** in my C project, i find this function is a built-in function in gcc.However, it seems that i cannot use it in visual studio 2019 and it shows **"__sync_fetch_and_add" is an undefined symbol**

Could anyone tell me if there is something wrong with my configuration or it relates to the development platform. If there is an alternative way to use the same function under vs 2019 with C laungage.

Comment: Right, it's a gcc-specific builtin, not part of standard C, and so you cannot expect other compilers to support it.  If you want atomic functionality with portability across compilers, that's what the `<stdatomic.h>` types and functions are for.  There are very few good reasons to use the `__sync_*` builtins these days.

Comment: I am really appreciate for your answer. And if it means that visual studio 2019 use other compilers instead of gcc?

Comment: I search and find vs2019 use MSVC toolchain, the complier of which is CL. It's different from gcc and not compatible with it.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio contains Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler, which has always been an entirely separate product from gcc.